# Error using usb flashdrive - what usb error codes mean?

Tags: usb, error-handling, dmesg

I have somewhat arbitrary errors when using a pendrive, as reported by dmesg:

```
[  306.904222] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  321.080172] usb 2-3: string descriptor 0 read error: -110
[  321.080191] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=125f, idProduct=c08a
[  321.080199] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  326.083021] usb 2-3: can't set config #1, error -110
```

My question is: what does the error code "-110" mean here? Pointer to the corresponding code of the Linux kernel can be helpful.

It is non-deterministic. The pendrive will often work, but fails randomly both in my Desktop machine and in my Dell XPS12 laptop running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like the command below (in a terminal).

```
strings /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-74/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h
```

Use uname-a to find out what kernel you are running, and use that in place of the 3.13.0-74 that is in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what that code means, but I had this error when I was trying to program my ARM, this reply was realy helpfull -> https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17618#p176143

To solve it I needed to disconnect my ARM microcontroller from st-link programator.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I see. @Ravexina should I edit my answer or delete it? (Because I see, that it does not so correspond to the asked question)